# How to remove <style> tag with JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to remove complete  tag and its content from html file, by JS.

My idea is to locate the  tags and locate the correct one by checking its content. Then using `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)` to remove this  tag and its content.
But the trials were failed. I also tried many other ways found on this site. All failed.

**What is the correct way to remove a specific `<style>` tag and its content ?**

The following are the code, you could also find it here https://codepen.io/puddlejumper26/pen/eYQwvaY

In order to compare, I also add method to remove the `<span>`, and it works fine, but for `<style>` it is not working.

In the codepen, you need to right click, and choose `view frame source` to check whether the stylings are removed.

```html
<style>
  #footer-desktop :root {
    --article-body-tablet-offset: rem(32px);
    --grid-6-1-column-content: calc(1 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*5))/6)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-6-1-column-content-gap: calc(1 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*5))/6)) + var(--grid-column-gap)));
    --grid-8-1-column-content: calc(1 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*7))/8)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-8-1-column-content-gap: calc(1 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*7))/8)) + var(--grid-column-gap)));
    --grid-8-2-column-content: calc(2 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*7))/8)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-8-3-column-content: calc(3 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*7))/8)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-8-4-column-content: calc(4 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*7))/8)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-10-1-column-content: calc(1 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*9))/10)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-10-2-column-content: calc(2 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*9))/10)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-10-3-column-content: calc(3 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*9))/10)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-10-4-column-content: calc(4 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*9))/10)) + var(--grid-column-gap)) - var(--grid-column-gap));
    --grid-10-1-column-content-gap: calc(1 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*9))/10)) + var(--grid-column-gap)));
    --grid-12-1-column-content-gap: calc(1 * ((((100% - (var(--grid-column-gap)*11))/12)) + var(--grid-column-gap)))
  }
</style>

<section class="_g-o">
      <div class="_g _g-lg fo_en">
        <div class="fo_en-c1">
          <span data-dtm-region="footer_ediciones-ep">
            test test
          </span>
        </div>      
    </div>
</section>
```

```js
 const styleNodes = document.querySelectorAll('style');

    styleNodes.forEach(node => {
      const result = node.textContent.includes(":root")
      if (result) {
        // console.log(1111, node.parentNode.childNodes)
        console.log(22222, node);
        node.textContent.replace(/(<style[\w\W]+style>)/g, " ");
        node.textContent.replace(/<style.*?<\/style>/g, '');
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        node.remove();
        console.log(33333, node.textContent)
      }
    })

const spanNode = document.querySelector('span')
// console.log(spanNode)
// spanNode.parentNode.removeChild(spanNode)
```

Comment: Unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish. Seems like a lot of code to remove stylesheet from the page. So why does `spanNode.remove()` not wok other than the selector is a bit generic and will select the first span on the page.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('style').forEach(ss => ss.disabled = ss.textContent.includes(':root'));` or `document.querySelectorAll('style').forEach(ss => ss.textContent.includes(':root') && ss.remove());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `remove()` on the DOM node is sufficient; you don't need to touch the parent node or try to rewrite the node's text contents.

```js
const styleNodes = document.querySelectorAll('style');
styleNodes.forEach(node => {
  if (node.textContent.includes(":root")) {
    node.remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- this style tag will stay -->
<style>
  body {background-color: blue}
</style>

<!-- this one will be removed -->
<style>
 body {background-color: red}
 .foo :root {}
</style>

Text Text Text
```